# Why my xml is not parsing properly?

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, saxparser

I want to parse my xml as below.
Actually I am trying to debug it, so control is not going to that School tag in the `startElement()` method.

```
<response>
 <school>
   <School>
      <id>1</id>
      <school_name>ABC</school_name>
      <logo/>
      <phone>+91-9764239061</phone>
   </School>
 </school>
</response>
```

- and my code is :

  private static final String TAG = SchoolParser.class.getName().toString();
      private List schoolListData ;
      private boolean isSuccess;
      private School school;
      private StringBuffer buffer;

  ```
  private boolean debug = true;


  public List<School> getSchoolListData(){
      return schoolListData;
  }


  @Override
  public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
      super.startDocument();
      schoolListData = new ArrayList<School>();
  }


  @Override
  public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
          Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
      super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes);
      Log.d("data in School Parser", "Inside");
      if(localName.equals("School")){
          printInfoLog("New school======>");
          school = new School();

      }else if(localName.equals("id")){
          Log.d("data in School Parser inside Localin", "Inside Local");

      }else if(localName.equals("school_name")){

      }else if(localName.equals("logo")){

      }else if(localName.equals("phone")){

      }

      Log.d("data in School Parser inside Localout", "Inside Local");

  }


  @Override
  public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
          throws SAXException {
      super.characters(ch, start, length);
      buffer.append(new String(ch, start, length));
      printInfoLog(buffer.toString());
  }



  @Override
  public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
          throws SAXException {
      super.endElement(uri, localName, qName);

      if(localName.equals("School")){
          printInfoLog("Add New School======>");
          schoolListData.add(school);
          school =null;
      }else if(localName.equals("id")){
          school.setId(Integer.parseInt(buffer.toString().trim()));
      }else if(localName.equals("school_name")){
          school.setSchoolName(buffer.toString().trim());
      }else if(localName.equals("logo")){
          school.setLogo(buffer.toString().trim().getBytes());
      }else if(localName.equals("phone")){
          school.setPhn_no(buffer.toString().trim());
      }
      //      int size = buffer.length(); 
      //      buffer.delete(0, size);
      Log.i("buffer is empty", ""+buffer.toString());
  }

  @Override
  public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
      super.endDocument();
      isSuccess = false;
  }

  private void printInfoLog(String msg){
      if(debug ){
          Log.i(TAG, msg);
      }
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: <response>
     <school>
       <School>
          <id>1</id>
          <school_name>ABC</school_name>
          <logo/>
          <phone>+91-9764239061</phone>
       </School>
     </school>
    </response>

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
if(localName.equals("School")){
    printInfoLog("Add New School======>");
    schoolListData.add(school);
    school =null;
}else if(localName.equals("id")){
    school.setId(Integer.parseInt(buffer.toString().trim()));
}else if(localName.equals("school_name")){
    school.setSchoolName(buffer.toString().trim());
}else if(localName.equals("logo")){
    school.setLogo(buffer.toString().trim().getBytes());
}else if(localName.equals("phone")){
    school.setPhn_no(buffer.toString().trim());
}
```

to

```
if(qName.equals("School")){
    printInfoLog("Add New School======>");
    schoolListData.add(school);
    school =null;
}else if(qName.equals("id")){
    school.setId(Integer.parseInt(buffer.toString().trim()));
}else if(qName.equals("school_name")){
    school.setSchoolName(buffer.toString().trim());
}else if(qName.equals("logo")){
    school.setLogo(buffer.toString().trim().getBytes());
}else if(qName.equals("phone")){
    school.setPhn_no(buffer.toString().trim());
}
```

Comment: @user2890202 also check if the startElement is called too :)

Comment: it is not checking the tags thats why it is giving NullPointerException..., But I have given proper tag names and compared it correctly...

Comment: m nt sure why, bt where is the .parse method called ? refer to [this for xml parsing in android](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/01/xml-parsing-using-saxparser-with.html)

Comment: that is in other class where I am calling, parser.parse(xmlStrem,new SchoolParser());

Comment: Main problem is, it is not detecting/comparing with tags..why is it so??

Comment: Log.i the localname and qname to see if there;s any data in it

Comment: it is not detecting the tag.. so How control goes inside to Log localname values

Comment: write the log i value immediately before the if condition, to check what localname and qnames it is detecting then ul know why its nt getting into the if

Comment: does localname contain anything ?? Log.i("tag","localName" + localName); check the value that localName contains, and also qName